"1984" style English Dystopian film/TV series
I have vague memories of an 1984 style movie (or possibly a TV series) set in 1980's England which is ruled by a fascist government. It would have been made in the 70's/80's and The only detail I remember clearly is that the secret police wore black "Nazi SS" style uniforms. The film explored similar themes to "1990" starring Edward Woodward (It definitely isn't "1990"). I know this isn't much to go on, but for some reason the black "SS" uniformed policemen stick in my mind.
Does anyone know what this film was called?

Could be Fahrenheit 451

Also you could check this list http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=dystopia&sort=moviemeter,asc&mode=detail&page=1&release_date=1965%2C1985&ref_=kw_ref_yr

It definitely wasn't Fahrenheit 451.

None of the films on the imdb list either, I'm thinking it may have been a mini series instead of a film.

Could be Brazil, which has black ss-style uniforms.

Found it on imdb after a bit of digging, it wasn't listed under Dystopian films and TV it was listed under Sci-Fi - Thriller.
It was a TV series called "The Guardians" - In the 1980's The UK has broken up and is ruled by a fascist police force - The Guardians.
